# Path conflict arrises when Testing the Js file having dependent file path

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am Testing the javascript file with jest which having dependent file path like

```
fs.readFileSync('../configuration_service/configuration_files/test.js')
```

If I test the above javascript file with jest, by importing into the test.js file, I am getting path mismatch exception. Is there any way to test those file, other than providing the full path detail (Because the javascript code should run on any machine.).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jest-plugin-fs](https://github.com/negativetwelve/jest-plugins/tree/master/packages/jest-plugin-fs) to mock out the filesystem.